# Create Company Card w/ Vpim Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, vpim

I'm using [Vpim](http://vpim.rubyforge.org/) to generate .vcf files that users can then import into their address books. The problem that I'm having is that the information that their downloading is for a Company and not a person so I need to mark the card as being such. Is there a way to do this using Vpim or is there another gem that I could use to accomplish this?

```
def to_vcf
  card = Vpim::Vcard::Maker.make2 do |maker|
  ...
  end
end
```

**Source of a Business Card from Address Book**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;;;;
FN:The Flow Skatepark
ORG:The Flow Skatepark;
item1.TEL;type=pref:(614) 864-1610
item1.X-ABLabel:Work #
item2.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;4252 Groves Rd;Columbus;OH;43232;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
BDAY;value=date:2001-07-06
X-ABShowAs:COMPANY
X-ABUID:5F7349CB-369F-4EAC-AB65-49ED902BEF9F\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

**Source of a Non-Business Card from Address Book**

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;The Flow Skatepark;;;
FN:The Flow Skatepark
item1.TEL;type=pref:(614) 864-1610
item1.X-ABLabel:Work #
item2.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;4252 Groves Rd;Columbus;OH;43232;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
BDAY;value=date:2001-07-06
X-ABUID:5F7349CB-369F-4EAC-AB65-49ED902BEF9F\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

Obviously there are two main differences in these code samples:

- ORG:The Flow Skatepark;
- X-ABShowAs:COMPANY

I don't know how this translates into Vpim however.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty implementation, I hope that I understood you correctly:

```
require 'vpim/vcard'

vcards = <<VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;;;;
FN:The Flow Skatepark
ORG:The Flow Skatepark;
item1.TEL;type=pref:(614) 864-1610
item1.X-ABLabel:Work #
item2.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;4252 Groves Rd;Columbus;OH;43232;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
BDAY;value=date:2001-07-06
X-ABShowAs:COMPANY
X-ABUID:5F7349CB-369F-4EAC-AB65-49ED902BEF9F\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:;The Flow Skatepark;;;
FN:The Flow Skatepark
item1.TEL;type=pref:(614) 864-1610
item1.X-ABLabel:Work #
item2.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;4252 Groves Rd;Columbus;OH;43232;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
BDAY;value=date:2001-07-06
X-ABUID:5F7349CB-369F-4EAC-AB65-49ED902BEF9F\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
VCARD

contacts = []
Vpim::Vcard.decode(vcards).each do |vcard|
  contacts << {
    first_name:        vcard.name      ? vcard.name.given         : '',
    last_name:         vcard.name      ? vcard.name.family        : '',
    organisation_name: vcard.org       ? vcard.org.first          : '',
  }
end

def to_vcard(card)
  Vpim::Vcard::Maker.make2 do |maker|
    maker.add_name do |name|
      name.given = card[:first_name] unless card[:first_name].empty? || card[:first_name].nil?
      name.family = card[:last_name] unless card[:last_name].empty?  || card[:last_name].nil?
    end
    maker.org = card[:organisation_name] unless card[:organisation_name].empty? || card[:organisation_name].nil?
  end
end

contacts.each_with_index do |contact, idx|
  File.open("contact#{idx}.vcf", 'w') {|f| f.write(to_vcard(contact)) }  
end
```

[image: Normal vs Company]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the maker object has a org= method, which you can use to set ORG. As for X-ABShowAs, maker has an add_field method. You can probably create your own field (http://vpim.rubyforge.org/classes/Vpim/DirectoryInfo/Field.html) for that.